# Решить задачу по базе Northwind SQL

Tags: sql

Показать товары, цена которых больше цены чая ('Chai') (решить через JOIN и подзапрос)

Удалось решить эту задачу с подзапросом но без JOIN'а. Куда выпихнуть JOIN?

```
 select ProductName, UnitPrice
 from Products
 where UnitPrice > (
                    select UnitPrice
                    from products
                    where UnitPrice = Products.UnitPrice and ProductName = 'chai'
                    )
```

Также есть наброски по запросу с JOINом, но почему-то запрос работает некорректно

```
 with chai
 as 
 (
select *
from products
where UnitPrice = Products.UnitPrice and ProductName = 'chai'
 )
  select Products.productname, Products.unitprice
  from chai join Products on Products.ProductID = chai.ProductID
  where Products.UnitPrice > chai.UnitPrice
```

Comment: не совсем вас понял каким образом переместить какое именно сравнение переместить из WHERE в ON. Если UnitPrice = Products.UnitPrice, то не выйдет, т.к. это не ключ и по нему не получится заджоинить. Получил такой запрос, но он выдает мне только наименование продукта 'Chai' и его цену) 

 select d.ProductName, d.UnitPrice
 from  (
  select *
  from products
  where ProductName = 'chai'
  ) as d join Products on Products.ProductID = d.ProductID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice
FROM Products 
JOIN ( SELECT UnitPrice
       FROM products
       WHERE ProductName = 'chai' 
    -- ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1
    -- вообще-то обязательно - вдруг для чая там больше одной записи?
      ) AS subquery ON Products.UnitPrice > subquery.UnitPrice;
```

Comment: первый раз вижу, что можно ставить что-то помимо знака "=" между столбцами, по которым мы делаем JOIN (ON Products.UnitPrice > subquery.UnitPrice). Впрочем наверное не удивительно, учитывая, что я не больше месяца в SQL. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Руслан Там можно писать всё, что угодно. Хоть подзапросы... Лишь бы оно было синтаксически корректно и давало результат BOOLEAN типа (или приводимого к нему, если СУБД осуществляет неявное приведение типов).